# How can I add icons to this force simulation example in d3js and avoid code duplication?

Tags: d3.js

I have two questions, one about the icons and other about code duplication.

I'm using this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/6184054/bd294b921ebf2180eccc3aca548c895367fca2d2

(Thanks Roger Veciana)

I want to add an icon to each of those cirlces but I need to put the url inside a json instead of using the script to generate those cirlces (that is inside the code). Not sure what I'm doing wrong but is not working. **Any tip on how can I add the icon to each circle ?**

I've also added some text, and it is working. Basically I do this:

```
var circlemaint = svgmaint.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes.maint)
    .enter().append("g").append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .call(d3.drag);

var txtmaint = svgmaint.selectAll("circle")
    .select('text')
    .data(nodes.maint)
    .enter().append('text')
    .text(node => node.id)
    .attr('font-size', 18)
    .attr('dx', -25)
    .attr('dy',20)
```

The issue here, is that I have 9 different svg's, and I don't want to duplicate this per svg. **How can avoid code duplication?**

I finally call it within the tick function and I do something like this:

```
function tick(e) {
    simulation.alpha(0.2)
circlemaint
        .each(gravity(this.alpha()))
        .each(collide(.5))
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

txtmaint
        .each(gravity(this.alpha()))
        .each(collide(.5))
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
circleXXXX
        ......
txtXXXXXX
        ......

}
```

And here is the code of the example:

```js
//Based in
///http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919
var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var rect = [50, 50, width - 50, height - 50];

var n = 20,
  m = 4,
  padding = 6,
  maxSpeed = 3,
  radius = d3.scale.sqrt().range([0, 8]),
  color = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(m));
var nodes = [];

for (i in d3.range(n)) {
  nodes.push({
    radius: radius(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)),
    color: color(Math.floor(Math.random() * m)),
    x: rect[0] + (Math.random() * (rect[2] - rect[0])),
    y: rect[1] + (Math.random() * (rect[3] - rect[1])),
    speedX: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * maxSpeed,
    speedY: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * maxSpeed
  });
}


var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .size([width, height])
  .gravity(0)
  .charge(0)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width", rect[2] - rect[0])
  .attr("height", rect[3] - rect[1])
  .attr("x", rect[0])
  .attr("y", rect[1])
  .style("fill", "None")
  .style("stroke", "#222222");

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color;
  })
  .call(force.drag);

var flag = false;

function tick(e) {
  force.alpha(0.1)
  circle
    .each(gravity(e.alpha))
    .each(collide(.5))
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}



// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    if ((d.x - d.radius - 2) < rect[0]) d.speedX = Math.abs(d.speedX);
    if ((d.x + d.radius + 2) > rect[2]) d.speedX = -1 * Math.abs(d.speedX);
    if ((d.y - d.radius - 2) < rect[1]) d.speedY = -1 * Math.abs(d.speedY);
    if ((d.y + d.radius + 2) > rect[3]) d.speedY = Math.abs(d.speedY);

    d.x = d.x + (d.speedX * alpha);
    d.y = d.y + (-1 * d.speedY * alpha);

  };
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + radius.domain()[1] + padding,
      nx1 = d.x - r,
      nx2 = d.x + r,
      ny1 = d.y - r,
      ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
          y = d.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 ||
        x2 < nx1 ||
        y1 > ny2 ||
        y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: How are you adding the 9 svgs? If they all have the same sort of data and show the same thing, you should be able to nest everything in a single nested enter, which would be the simplest way. Does each SVG also have a force simulation?

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid I have One global svg and 9 childs. Each svg have force simulation, and I have a json similar to this: ```{
  "svg1": [
    "id": "server1",
    "x": example,
    "y": example2
  ],
  "svg2": [
    "id": "server2",
    "x": example,
    "y": example2

}``` Then to load the nodes: .data(nodes.svg1). Thank you so much !

Comment: And I add the svgs like this @AndrewReid
```<svg id="global" width="1920" height="970">

        <svg id="svg1" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="470"></svg>

        <svg id="svg2" x="0" y="474" width="200" height="162"></svg>

       ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - will take a look when I'm less busy.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewReid ! I really appreciate your help.